# how to use buildQuery query productState!='a' and productState!='b'

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to query a product via its ipNum (ie already exists) and productState not equal  'REVOKE' and not equal 'SOLD'. When I query only

```
productState != 'REVOKE'
```

it does work, but when I query

```
productState != 'REVOKE' and != 'SOLD'
```

it does not work

Answer (score 0):

1. in reference to `ipNum` - this field (as per Rocketchat https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/composer?msg=naiTMBZdaikSs4Qps ),  is not a field of the `Product` asset -  so your problem is likely to be the `intellectualProperty.ipNum` comparison   - you can't you use a 'stepped reference'in a query for a relationship (in another asset class) - eg suggest to cross-check a different way in your query processor function, or use an if comparison with the `inputValue` in your code, before invoking the query for checking `Product` fields
2. it seems ANDing (ie the same field value being evaluated) for double NOTs does not work in [underlying] couchDB query language (returns all) when its the same field. eg

   ```
   const q = buildQuery("SELECT org.xfb.ipchain.Product WHERE ( (productState != 
     'REVOKE') AND (productState != 'SOLD') )");
     const results = await query(q);
     console.log("results are " + results); // returns all status

     results.forEach(function(res){
           console.log("result instance is " + res.id + " " + res.status);
             });
   ```

You might want to reconsider your status query design.

Comment: Thanks Paul,i tested the query ,double NOTs does not work in [underlying] couchDB query language  when its the same field.